# Can't get object properties in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm having trouble displaying my object details in the html view (using ionic2).  The below outputs the correct value in the cart.ts file(outputs carrot).

```
this.cart = resultsFromAPI     
console.log(this.cart.vegetable);
```

However when I try to output it in the view it won't let me view the page any longer.  I'm assuming because of an error.

```
<h2>{{cart.vegetable}}</h2>
```

If I output just the object I get the [object Object] in the header

```
<h2>{{cart}}</h2>
```

It looks like the error is "Cannot read property 'vegetable' of undefined".  How can I read it in the ts but not the view?

Below is full ts code

```
 cart:any;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getPosts(this.category, this.limit);
  }

  getPosts(category, limit){
    this.cartService.getPosts(category, limit).subscribe(response => {
      this.cart = response.data.children;
      console.log( this.cart.vegetable);
    });
  }
```

Answer:
I followed the post below but had to put the return before the call

```
public getPosts$(category, limit) {
  return this.cartService.getPosts(category, limit).map(response => {
       this.cart = response.data.children;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you're doing an async API call, so you should check if its available before using it. Furthermore you could use the API Response directly as an Observable via `async` pipe.

```
<h2>{{(cart | async)?.vegetable}}</h2>
```

For OP edit:
You could just write (the $ at the end of the fname means it's a stream):

```
public getPosts$(category, limit) {
  return this.cartService.getPosts(category, limit).map(response => {
   return response && response.data && response.data.children;
  };
}
```

and:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.getPosts$(this.category, this.limit).subscribe(cart => {
  this.cart = cart;
 }
}
```

and:

```
<h2 *ngIf="cart>{{cart.vegetable}}</h2>
```

Comment: When I call the function in the ngOnInit I get "property subscribe does not exsist on void".

Comment: @Matt checkout your service code, it seem you do not return an Observable from this.cartService.getPosts method

Comment: I'm still learning and followed a tutorial to this point.  Below is the getPosts      getPosts(category, limit){
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl+'/'+category+'/top.json?limit='+limit)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

Comment: It was my bad, i corrected my code above, i missed a return statement

Comment: thank you for the help, much appreciated.  I can't seem to run an if (I get the same error).  In the tutorial I followed they bring in an array and loop through it and it works fine.  However when I bring one object to the view I am having these issues.  I posted the new question.  Again thank you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985595/cannot-read-property-of-undefined-angular2-ngif