# Cannot read property of undefined angular2 ngif

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am now able to get the object in the view however I cannot run an if statement.  Per previous answer this is how I am bringing in the object.

```
public getPosts$(category, limit) {
  return this.cartService.getPosts(category, limit).map(response => {
    return response && response.data && response.data.children;
  };
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.getPosts$(this.category, this.limit).subscribe(cart => {
    this.cart = cart;
  }
}
```

I am trying to run but get cannot get property vegetable.

```
<h2 *ngIf="cart">{{cart.vegetable}}</h2>
<h2 *ngIf="cart.vegetable == 'carrot' ">{{cart.vegetable}}</h2>
```

The error is

> Cannot read property 'vegtable' of undefined

Comment: not sure if just a typo put you are missing closing `"` after `cart` in your if statement

Comment: 1) What is the exact error? 2) You are doing an assignment in your 2nd ngIf 3) You're missing a " in your first ngIf.

Comment: 1)the error is "Cannot read property 'vegtable' of undefined" 2)typo sorry 3)It was a typo - fixed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `cart` object is null until the service `getPosts$` returns (callback). Therefore, the code `*ngIf="cart.vegetable ...` is equal to `*ngIf="null.vegetable ...` until that happens. That is what is happening.

What you could do is put a DOM element with `*ngIf="cart"` containing the other `*ngIf`. For example:

```
<div *ngIf="cart">
    <h2 *ngIf="cart.vegetable == 'carrot' ">{{cart.vegetable}}</h2>
</div>
```

*Edit: As it is said in the next answer, a good alternative (and good practice) is the following:

`<h2 *ngIf="cart?.vegetable == 'carrot' ">{{cart.vegetable}}</h2>`

Answer (score 19):

Use the safe-navigation operator to guard against `null` or `undefined` for async fetched data:

```
<h2 *ngIf="cart?.vegetable == 'carrot' ">{{cart.vegetable}}</h2>
```

Comment: the property vegetable is there.  If I leave it as <h2 *ngIf="cart>{{cart.vegetable}}</h2> I get a value.  I want to test that value against a string

Comment: I didn't know about this feature. Thanks! This should be the accepted answer - much more elegant than wrapping in another element, especially if the property you want to access is nested several levels deep in an object.

Comment: Is this operator part of Angular or JS?

Comment: At the time I posted this it was Angular-only but there was a proposal for JS/TS. I don't know if it was implemented since. It's a while I worked in this area.

Answer (score 0):

I used `{{ }}` while they are not needed. Getting rid of them fixed it for me.

So this

```
<li *ngIf="{{house}}">
```

Should be

```
<li *ngIf="house">
```