# Waiting for remote data before rendering in Angular 2

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm trying to get JSON data from remote server and pass it into template as `page` object.

But when I try to get value of `page.name` inside template, getting error that says:

`Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

On other hand, `console.log` shows correct data coming from server.

Looks like, render process doesn't wait for data to be received first.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Here are my `.ts` files:

## `app.component.ts`

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {PageService} from './page.service';
import {Page} from './page';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  providers: [PageService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  page: Page;

  constructor(private pageSrv: PageService) {
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.pageSrv.getData(2802).then((result) => {
      this.page = result;
      console.log(this.page);
    });
  }
}
```

## `page.service.ts`

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {Page} from './page';

@Injectable()
export class PageService {


  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  getData(id: number): Promise<Page> {
    return this.http.get('http://example.com/items/' + id + '?expand=categories,comments,modifications,tags,media,fileFields')
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json() as Page)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

## `page.ts`

```
export class Page {
  id: number;
  slug: string;
  name: string;
  sell_price: string;
  details: string;
  excerpt: string;
  imgUri: string;
  created_at: string;
  rating: number;
  categories: Array<any>;
  comments: Array<any>;
  media: Array<any>;
  tags: Array<any>;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot read property of undefined angular2 ngif](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985595/cannot-read-property-of-undefined-angular2-ngif)

Comment: Add a safe navigation operator to your html. Like `{{page?.name}}`

Comment: @echonax you're a lifesaver. Thanks. helped me a lot

Comment: @echonax convert it to answer so I can vote for it

Comment: @Heiros it's better to mark duplicate questions :-) I just wanted you to get the answer quickly since it was a small thing to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initialize `page` variable as empty object.